# Consume more than one WCF service in same orchestration

Tags: wcf, biztalk, biztalk-2009

I need to consume two WCF services in the same orchestration.

I use the "Consume WCF Service Wizard" that generates the xsd, xml, messages, pots and a orchrestation for each service

The thing is I can't use all the multipart messages generated just in one orchestration, I just can use the ones from the service it was generated from

I think it might have a simple solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you create a separate "Schemas" Project for the schemas and bindings generated by the Wizard.

Reference this Project from your "Orchestrations" project and re-create multi-part messages for the schemas.

You don't need to use the auto-generated multi-part messages as you can create your own;

Just create a request multi-part message with a Body and set the message type to the appropriate schema in your referenced Schema project.

This is the most flexible way I can think of to achieve your objective.

HTH